# How to integrate custom skins into a jQuery webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

**Edit:
tl;dr What I have is a .png file of a horizontal bar and a .png file of a square button. I want to be able to add both images to a webpage and be able to slide the button along the rectangle. I know that it is possible to make range sliders in better ways but using the .png files is a hard requirement.**

I have been tasked with taking an image of a range slider, adding it to a webpage, and make the slider interactive/draggable. I know that jQuery has its own sliders (https://jqueryui.com/slider/#multiple-vertical) but this does not seem to apply if you want to use an image of the range slider instead.

Example Image:
[image: sample range slider]
<sub>(source: [dcrazed.com](https://dcrazed.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/price-range-slider.jpg))</sub>

How can this be implemented? All the tutorials I see make the slider out of HTML/CSS/JS elements while I have separate images of the slider and draggable button.

FYI, the reason we're using an image is that it looks better than the standard sliders jQuery provides.

Comment: Are you looking for a slider with a custom tooltip?  If so there are plenty of code examples available on the web.  Google is your friend.

Comment: My apologies. Bad example image. The slider does not have a tooltip, nor is it desired. What I have is a .png file of a horizontal bar and a .png file of a square button. I want to be able to add both images to a webpage and be able to slide the button along the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

It may help if you search for "Form Range Input" or "RangeSlider JS" instead of slider to find a tutorial.

However I don't see any reason why this can't be accomplished more easily and more cleanly strictly through JS and CSS.

If you're having trouble visualising, try breaking your design into parts like so and save yourself the hassle of trying to make an image based design responsive. (Like we all have struggled with previously)

---

1. The slider knob itself is a rounded square with three squares inside it.
2. The slider bar is a rounded rectangle with another three squares placed inside it.
3. The information box is a div with text and a [CSS triangle](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) affixed to it.
4. The ticks themselves are trickier and will need to be added and removed dynamically with JS depending on their resolution, but their visual details only really need basic styling

---

If you still feel the need to use images and break the responsiveness of your website then have a look through some Codepens and see what others have done with similar requirements.

Comment: Thanks James. I took a look at Codepens and it seemed like everyone was using the standard range slider instead of using an image. The image unfortunately is a hard requirement.